# use location tag in web.config to remove settings for a child app

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, web-config, location

hi i am trying to run a child application inside a sub folder of my asp.net website. The web.config file of my child application inherits from the root web.config and will not compile when i try to access the path.

I would like to switch settings in the web.config depending on the path using 
     
as this is how all the solutions i have read deal with this issue. Unfortunately they all use inheritInChildApplications which has been removed from .net 4

My web application project is named Dating and the folder that contains the child application is called Mobile

i have tried various combinations of the following in my root web.config

```
<location path="Mobile" allowOverride="true" >
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="." allowOverride="true">
  <system.web>

    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15360" requestLengthDiskThreshold="15360" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trace localOnly="false" mostRecent="true" pageOutput="true" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="Dating" applicationName="Dating" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Dating" applicationName="Dating" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="15" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="YafProfileProvider" inherits="YAF.Utils.YafUserProfile">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="Dating" applicationName="Dating" name="YafProfileProvider" type="YAF.Providers.Profile.YafProfileProvider" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <!--<profile inherits="Dating.WebProfile.UserProfile" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomizedProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="Dating" applicationName="Dating"/>
      </providers>

    </profile>-->
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <controls>
        <!--<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajx"/>-->
        <!--<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" /> -->
        <add tagPrefix="ajx" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <!-- Default: use non-dynamic (compiled classes) in YAF -->
        <add tagPrefix="YAF" namespace="YAF.Controls" assembly="YAF.Controls" />
        <add tagPrefix="YAF" namespace="YAF.Controls.Statistics" assembly="YAF.Controls" />
        <add tagPrefix="YAF" namespace="YAF.Classes" />
        <add tagPrefix="YAF" namespace="YAF" />
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="YAF.Core" />
        <add namespace="YAF.Controls" />
        <add namespace="YAF.Utils" />
        <add namespace="YAF.Types.Interfaces" />
        <add namespace="YAF.Types" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  </location>
```

i would like the settings taken from the mobile web.config to override the settings in the root but this does not appear to happen. i get the following error

Could not load file or assembly 'YAF.Core' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'YAF.Core' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having done lots of research I have found that the inheritance of web configs is very tricky.

This article is very helpful and sums up how this works very concisely

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx

I have decided the quickest solution for my problem is to setup the mvc app as a subdomain.

In future a good solution i think is to have a base site with no changes to the web.config. Then setup a descendant site from this to give you the option to setup a sibling site that does not inherit from any other descendant sites web.cofig but is still part of the same site.